# Jquery for dynamic checkbox is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am using the below code to get the selected chnaeckboxes. These checkboxes are dynamically added inside **XSLT**.

```
//html
<div id="centerNameChk">
<input type="checkbox" name="emailList" onclick="">
Add Workforce Center to email
</input>
</div>

//jquery
if ($("#centerNameChk :checked").size() > 0) {
  //my code is here
}
```

The above code is working fine in FF, Chrome, but in IE the `$("#centerNameChk :checked").size()` is always returing 0.

I am using jQuery 1.4.2 and i updated to 1.7.2 but still the same issue.

Any suggestions...

Thanks

Comment: Try this selector : `$("#centerNameChk input:checked")`

Comment: the above code is always true.....

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if ($("#centerNameChk :checkbox").is(":checked")​​​​​) {
  // my code is here
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Uzstj/)**.

Comment: alert($("#centerNameChk :checkbox").is(":checked")); is always giving false for me... Does the jquery version matters..i tried jquery 1.7.2 but still same issue